# Write shrunken .img file to device file

Tags: linux, shell, files, devices, dd

I have a backup image of a device file `/dev/sda3` that I created using:

`dd if=/dev/sda3 of=~/sda3.img`.

The image is very large, so I have re-sized it to remove empty space. My question is can I write the shrunken image back to `/dev/sda3` with

`dd if=~/sda3.img of=/dev/sda3`

without messing up the partition(s) or altering the device file size for `/dev/sda3`?

In the past I've been able to do this, but I'd like to get some technical information about this operation.

Secondly, let's assume I know where the device file starts and ends in `/dev/sda`.

Can I write the shrunken backup image directly to `/dev/sda`, using something like :

`dd if=~/sda3.img seek=2048 count=4096`,

without messing up the partition table or altering the file size for `/dev/sda3` and other `/dev/sda` devices?

I do not want to compress the image file with something like `gzip` and then `gunzip` the compressed file to `dd` , to write it to disk.

I will likely be accessing the backed up image file regularly via loop mount to grab data from it, so storing it as a compressed image file is not a good option.

Comment: What do you mean by “re-sized”? Did you truncate it? Did you resize the filesystem?